# Is is possible to configure settings in Bitbucket globally?

Tags: bitbucket

It is possible to configure settings per repository in Bitbucket. Would it be possible to configure settings globally? There are more than 30 repositories at the moment and I would like to avoid that I have to configure the same settings per repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this seems not to be possible in bitbcuket at the moment. Therefore I have created [an enhancement in the Bitbucket issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/15301/as-an-administrator-i-can-configure).